# Multiple hover instances jQuery

Tags: javascript, animation, hover, multiple-instances, mouseenter

I have a div to animate from the top to the bottom of another div. I'm currently playing w/ mouseenter/leave and JS animations w/ easing where its original state is up/top. I want to hover/mouseenter and have it move down and stay down if I mouseleave/hover off. When I hover again it will animate back to the top/start.

I initially used mouseenter/leave which obviously doesn't do what I need as I would like the state to remain the same upon mouseleave. So what function would be best for this need? I'm still learning the terminology and am stumbling over how to better phrase the question.

Code:

```
    function init() { 
        mouseenter: function(){
            $(".ltrP").stop(true, true).animate({
                marginTop:"170px"
            }, 
            {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: "easeOutBounce"
            });
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            $(".ltrP").stop(true, true).animate({
                marginTop: "0px"
            },
            {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: "easeInBounce"
            });   
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your piece of code, see the comments for explanation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Runs when document is loaded

    $(".ltrP").mouseenter(function(){ // Mouseenter event on the given object (.ltrP)
        var goTo = $(this).css("marginTop") == '0px' ? 170 : 0; // When the current margin-top is 0px animate to 170px, otherwise animate it back to 0px
        $(this).stop(true,false).animate({ // Changed the stop(true, true) to stop(true, false), looks nicer in my opinion
            marginTop: goTo // Animate to the just set variable
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

And see here a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hnDmt/

(And the easing "easeInBounce" was not working for me, so I removed it. (Maybe a jQuery UI easing?))

Comment: Thanks Lumocra! I selected this answer because it seems very flexible for working with other situations and well noted for future learning needs/tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    init();
});
function init() {
    $.hover(function(){
        $(".ltrP").stop(true, true).animate({
            marginTop:"170px"
        }, 
        {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: "easeOutBounce"
        });
    },
    function(){
        $(".ltrP").stop(true, true).animate({
            marginTop: "0px"
        },
        {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: "easeInBounce"
        });   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this. Maybe the easiest to to conceptualize is by adding a class to the animated item. You want to write two separate mouseenter functions.

For the first function, trigger your down animation, and add a class to the entered item. Call the class "moveddown" or something obvious.

Then, write a second mouseenter function. When an item with the class is mousentered, animate it up, and remove the class.

Forget about jQuery `hover` for this. It's just a wrapper for mouseenter/mouseleave. It can cause problems. The jQuery docs warn about it. It's usually better to write mouseenter and mouseleave functions separately, especially when you're trying to do something tricky, like this.